# JavaScript scope, function as method of object

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, scope, closures

I am having some trouble with JavaScript scope here, and I don't understand why.
My code is as follows:

```
var objArray = [] //imagine full array
function addDo(){
    for(var i = 0; i< objArray.length; i++){
        objArray[i].do = function(){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that i is always logged as `undefined`. How can I make this work? I've had similar problems with async calls, but managed to work around them with closures. Could I do the same here?

Comment: It can't log `undefined` with your code. unless you set `i = undefined` after for loop.

Comment: Read this for JavaScript Scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript